# The polytope and its projection cross-polytope

Tags: polynomials, convex-geometry

The $n$-dimensional cross-polytope:

$$C_n=\{x\in \mathbf{R}^n : \pm x_1 \pm x_2 \cdots \pm x_n \leq 1\}$$

How to realize $C_n$ is the projection on the $x$-coordinate of the polytope:    $$Q_n=\{(x,y)\in \mathbf{R}^{2n} :\sum_{i=1}^n y_i=1,-y_i\leq x_i \leq y_i, \forall i = 1,\ldots,n\}$$

> How to understand this from the definition of projection?

It looks like we can sum them up:

$$-(\sum y_i)\leq \sum x_i \leq \sum y_i \Rightarrow -1 \leq \sum x_i \leq 1$$

However, I still cannot understand why $C_n$ is the projection of $Q_n$

Comment: Double inclusion is the way to go here, as is often the case.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy What I really want to ask is the "projection" part? How to see this is a projection?

Comment: You don't really need to know what a projection is. Denote by $P_n$ the projection of $Q_n$. Then, you need to show the double inclusion $P_n\subseteq C_n$ and $C_n\subseteq P_n$. To check the first inclusion, show that for every $(x,y)\in Q_n$ we have $x\in C_n$. To check the second inclusion, show that for every $x\in C_n$ there is a $y\in {\mathbf{R}^n}$ such that $(x,y)\in Q_n$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy I see your point. Your answer implies the projection.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The linear map $\pi : \mathbb{R}^{2n} \to \mathbb{R}^{2n}$, $(x,y) \mapsto (x,0)$ is referred to as a $\textit{projection}$, a quick google search gives you the general [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)), and it is immediate to check that $\pi$ indeed satisfies $\pi^2=\pi$. When we say that $C_n$ is the projection of $Q_n$ under $\pi$, we mean that $\pi(Q_n)=C_n$. As pointed out in the comments, you can prove this equality by double inclusion.

As to the origin of the term, imagine in the case $n=1$, that a light illuminates the plane from above, and consider a point $p:=(x,y)$. Then, the point $(x,0)=\pi(p)$ is the "shadow" of $p$ on the line $y=0$ under the light, that is, its "projection". Does this help?